# It is such a nice place

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

'is' or 'was': Which would be more appropriate in the context?

A few years ago, i visited London. It ***is/was*** such a nice place, probably the best place i have ever been to.

I think 'is' should be used because the rest of the sentence is in present perfect tense. But i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you see it now - as a place which is worse or as a place which is still nice.

- *A few years ago, I visited London. It **is** such a nice place.* - I still think it's a nice place.
- *A few years ago, I visited London. It **was** such a nice place.* - It's not a nice place anymore but a few years ago it was. Maybe it was destroyed or maybe nobody can visit it anymore because it doesn't exist?